# Loading PostCSS "default" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'default', WebPack 5

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, loader, postcss

I'm fairly new to webpack and trying to create a configuration that uses postcss, typescript, react, and sass.It seems to only be erroring out on the styling scss imports but gives an error of postcss default plugin even though I know that it's installed as a dev dependency. Im using webpack merge to manage the production and development environments.

*Error*

Loading PostCSS "default" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'default'
node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].use[2]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/components/StylesLoading/StylesLoading.module.scss
Require stack:

*Project Tree*

```
├─ .gitignore
├─ .prettierrc
├─ babel.config.js
├─ package.json
├─ postcss.config.js
├─ public
│  └─ index.html
├─ src
│  ├─ App.tsx
│  ├─ components
│  │  └─ StylesLoading
│  │     ├─ StylesLoading.module.scss
│  │     └─ StylesLoading.tsx
│  ├─ global.d.ts
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ index.js
│  ├─ index.tsx
├─ stylelint.config.js
├─ tsconfig.json
├─ webpack.config.js
├─ webpack.dev.js
├─ webpack.prod.js
└─ yarn.lock
```

*global.d.ts*

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: Record<any,any>;
  export default content;
}
```

*babel.config.js*

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"){
  plugins.push("react-refresh/babel")
}

module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env",["@babel/preset-react", {"runtime":"automatic"}], "@babel/typescript"],
  plugins: plugins,
}
```

*webpack.common.config.js*

```
const path = require('path');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
module.exports = {
  entry: {
      main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.tsx'),
      vendor: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'vendor.tsx')
    },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.[contentHash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    assetModuleFilename: "images/[hash][ext][query]",
  },
  target:"web",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss','.ts', '.tsx'], // accepted file extensions
    modules:[
        path.join(__dirname, './node_modules')
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
            test:/\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use:{
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                }
            }
        },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        use: ['html-loader']
      },
      {
          test:/\.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        type:"asset",
        parser:{
            dataUrlCondition:{
                maxSize: (30 * 1024) //distinguishes images size from base64 to seperate assets
            }
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
  })],
  devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 8888,
    hot:true
  }
};
```

*webpack.dev.js*

```
const path = require('path')
const common = require('./webpack.config')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = merge(common, {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.tsx'),
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // test : /\.(s[ac]|c)ss$/i,
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: { publicPath: '' },
                    },
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                        },
                    },
                    { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader' },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name].css', chunkFilename: '[id].css' }),
        new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
    },
})
```

*PostCss config*

```
const plugins = [
    require('postcss-preset-env'),
    require('postcss-assets'), // manages cache busting of assets
    require('stylelint'), //  css linter -- airbnb
    require('stylelint-scss'),
    require('postcss-reporter'), // returns css warnings to address changes in ui
    require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss'), //removes unused css
    require('postcss-fail-on-warn'),
]

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
    plugins
        .push(require('autoprefixer')) // adds vendor prefixes for different browsers
        .push(require('cssnano'))
}

module.exports = {
    plugins: plugins,
}
```

*Package json start command*

```
scripts:{
...
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --open",
}
```